# Checking byte with bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I could use this:

```
unsigned long alpha = 140 | 130 << 8 | 255 << 16;
```

to set `140` to the first byte of `alpha`, `130` to the second and `255` as 3rd.
How do I do the opposite (i.e checking a specific byte of `alpha`) ?

---

```
alpha & 255 // works for the first byte
alpha >> 16; // works for the 3rd byte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift the value x bits to the right and then use AND to restrict the number of bits you use. ie: `(n >> 8) & 0xff` or `(n >> 16) & 0xff`.

Comment: other than the shifting is being performed to the right, rather than to the left, this is a good answer.

Comment: Thank you! I should suspect this.